Editing a forestplot
I try to edit a forestplot that is showing the results from a meta-analysis, using the following code:
forest(res1, header.line = "both", cex = 0.75,  xlim = c(0.2, 20), at = c(0.5, 1, 2.44, 10), common = FALSE, random = TRUE)
Forestplot
However, I want to change a few things:

By default, the plot is showing columns with 'logOR' and 'SE(logOR); how to remove these columns?
How to change the names of the columns? For example, I want to change the column name 'Odds Ratio' into 'adjusted Odds Ratio', how to do this? I already tried to work with 'header', 'header.names' and 'labeltext', but the plot does not change...
How to add a new column showing the variable 'study_year'?

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!
